# Android: Recyclerview, Data binding and View Model

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-volley, viewmodel

My goal is to display the results of an HTTP request in a recyclerview. Because I haven't worked with Android for a while, I want to use the most preferred method possible.

I have a Device data class:

```
data class Device(val name: String, val ipAddress: String, val type: String = "")
```

A NewDeviceAdapter:

```
class NewDevicesAdapter(private val items: List<Device>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NewDevicesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var binding: AdapterNewDevicesBinding


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ViewHolder(
            AdapterNewDevicesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) = holder.bind(items[position])

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: AdapterNewDevicesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Device) {
            binding.device = item
        }
    }
}
```

with the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="device"
            type="[...].Device" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            [...]

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adapter_newDevices_textView_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{device.name}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adapter_newDevices_textView_ip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{device.ipAddress}" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And a NewDeviceFragment class:

```
class NewDeviceFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNewDeviceBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentNewDeviceBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            devicesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this@NewDeviceFragment).get(DevicesViewModel::class.java)
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        }

        [...]

        binding.devicesViewModel!!.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            binding.newDeviceRecyclerViewDevices.adapter = NewDevicesAdapter(response as List<Device>)
        })

        return binding.root
    }
```

with xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="devicesViewModel"
            type="[...].DevicesViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        [...]

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/newDevice_recyclerView_devices"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/adapter_new_devices"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newDevice_toolbar" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I have a ViewModel class that is supposed to collect data via an HTTP request, which is then stored in a LiveData object to be displayed in the recyclerview via an observer in the fragment:

```
class DevicesViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val items: MutableLiveData<List<Device>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Device>>()
    }

    init {
        scanForDevices()
    }


    private fun scanForDevices() = {
        val newDevices: MutableList<Device> = arrayListOf()
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue()

        for (i in 100..255) {
            val ipAddress = "192.168.2.$i"
            val url = "$ipAddress/cm?cmnd=STATUS"
            [...]
        }
    }
```

But for the Volley RequestQueue I need a context which does not exist in the ViewModel. Now I have heard about the AndroidViewModel, but I am not sure if this is the right way. Maybe someone can give me a recommendation how I can / should best implement the concept with an HTTP request and the results in a Recyclerview.

Comment: Using AndroidViewModel is absolutely fine or you can use Hillt which is a DI framework and inject context in the ViewModel which is also a viable solution

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use context inside your Viewmodel you can use AndroidViewModel (AVM), because it contains the application context. To retrieve the context call getApplication(), otherwise use the regular ViewModel (VM).

If you use a regular VM, PASS application or context in scanForDevices() as parameter.

For unit testing purposes, Android VM is not the  best choice as its best to avoid anything that involves android lifecycle related objects, but if you still wanna use Android VM , use Dependency injection via Dagger 2 or Hilt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **Application context** which is provided by the **AndroidViewModel**, you should extend `AndroidViewModel` which is simply a ViewModel that includes an Application reference.

```
DevicesViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext
```